# how to delete cookies in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I would like to know can we delete cookie from cookies collection what we have created in asp.net website.I tried & find Expiration Logic.It works but it shows in browser cookie.

```
 Response.Cookies["UserID"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

Is there any other way by this we can delete cookies from collection so it will not show in browser cookies.

Please help me to solve the issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195.aspx):

> You cannot directly delete a cookie on
>   a user's computer. However, you can
>   direct the user's browser to delete
>   the cookie by setting the cookie's
>   expiration date to a past date. The
>   next time a user makes a request to a
>   page within the domain or path that
>   set the cookie, the browser will
>   determine that the cookie has expired
>   and remove it.

So, your strategy is the right one, and the cookie should disappear from the browser once the response is received.

Comment: Thanks,Actually i tried with above code it works but when i back to check in system it still shows last content record,That's why i thought to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can delete the cookie since you don't have access to delete anything on the client computer. All you can do is basically what you are doing, that is invalidating the cookie for your application. I think it is up to the client software to decide if the cookie should be deleted or not, all you can do is set the timestamp as you are doing and that means that you will no longer accept that cookie.